# Getting specific value from http response body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xmlhttprequest

I can not get the value from an http response body.

I've used `JSON.parse()` on the response.body I get as well as `xml-js` library. The value I have to get is '`P01`'.
This is the response:

```
{  
   "Soap:Envelope":{  
      "_attributes":{  
         "xmlns:Soap":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      },
      "Soap:Body":{  
         "ValidateUser_Result":{  
            "_attributes":{  
               "xmlns":"urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/UserValidation"
            },
            "return_value":{  
               "_text":"P01"
            }
         }
      }
    }
}
```

and here is what I've tried:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data["Soap:Envelope"]["Soap:Body"]["ValidateUser_Result"]["return_value"])));
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: `response["Soap:Envelope"]["Soap:Body"].ValidateUser_Result.return_value` edit: fixed

Comment: @ChrisG, you forgot "Soap:Envelope"

Comment: It's a Javascript object, not JSON. If you need to know how to get values from it, see any Javascript tutorial for beginners, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: It should be noted that the above code snippet shows a JavaScript Object literal. JSON is a textual format. There's no such thing as a JSON Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var o = {  
   "Soap:Envelope":{  
      "_attributes":{  
         "xmlns:Soap":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      },
      "Soap:Body":{  
         "ValidateUser_Result":{  
            "_attributes":{  
               "xmlns":"urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/UserValidation"
            },
            "return_value":{  
               "_text":"P01"
            }
         }
      }
    }
};

var val = o['Soap:Envelope']['Soap:Body']['ValidateUser_Result']['return_value']['_text'];

console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick.

```js
const data = {  
   "Soap:Envelope":{  
      "_attributes":{  
         "xmlns:Soap":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      },
      "Soap:Body":{  
         "ValidateUser_Result":{  
            "_attributes":{  
               "xmlns":"urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/UserValidation"
            },
            "return_value":{  
               "_text":"P01"
            }
         }
      }
    }
}
console.log(data["Soap:Envelope"]["Soap:Body"]["ValidateUser_Result"]["return_value"]["_text"]);
```